# Replace XFCE Power Manager with Gnome Power Manager

Tags: 11.10, power-management, xfce, gnome-power-manager

Is there a way to "swap-out" the existing XFCE power manager in a Xubuntu install with the more common GNOME power manager without breaking the install?

Am having problems with the xfce power manager on a Toshiba laptop (wont suspend properly) - whereas the gnome equivalent has always worked flawlessly in the past.

So how does one then go about removing the XFCE PM and replacing it with the GNOME power manager module?

Running Xubuntu 11.10 64 bit edition.

Answer (score 1):

Just uninstall and replace. Both are perfectly interchangeable, since they support the same DBus interface and hook up with udev.

Comment: really? when i try to remove xfce power manager it says it has to remove lubuntu-desktop too.

Comment: That's just a metapackage. Removing it won't do much harm